# Best way to move few rows and their related child rows from one table to another table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-replication, amazon-aurora

- We are offering a SAAS based product and for database, we are using MYSQL Compatible AWS Aurora 5.7.
- To overcome the issue of large number of rows in one table, We have created the multiple groups of tables(g1_, g2_, g3_, etc). Like our application has around 350 tables then there are 350 tables with g1_ prefix, 350 tables with g2_ prefix, and so on.
- Each group is having our multiple client's data like the `g1_customer` table has 5 our client's customers.

Now, the number of rows growing in each table and we want to move the one specific client's all data from one group to another group.

1. **Solution 1 in our mind:**
   We can keep the client id each table(master and child) and get all data from each source table by client id and insert it into the respective table to the target group.

**Issue:** The child table's row mapping, The target group tables can have the existing rows, and the source group master table's row will get a new autoincrement id here, so respective child table's row mapping would not be possible.

2. **Solution 2 in our mind:**
   Write a script that will get a single row and insert it into the target table, then get related rows from the chile table insert into the target child table, map with new autoincrement id, and so on.

**Issue:** This process will be very slow with large dataset (2.1 million rows)

Please share your best idea or any tool to achieve it.

Comment: If data of different clients are not related in any way, why not just have one database per client?

Comment: That solution is already working here on top of the group, that we called a cluster. Database1->group1,group2,group3, Database2->group4,group5, Database3->group6 and so on.. this three database could be on same or different database server. but still, data moving will reqired at some point.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Why don't you use one database per client? You wouldn't have this problem now.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel we have around 20k clients and maintaining single DB for each client will involve more maintenance of 20k DB, also not all client is so big to have separate DB for each.

Answer (score 0):

Let's back up and look at whether the proposed solution is the best.

In general, splitting one table (on one set of tables) into a set of identical tables is counter-productive.  It involves changing the client code to first pick which table, then proceed to use the desired table.  Often performance suffers rather than benefits.

Regardless of the approach, we cannot really help you without having

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE
and the various queries that would be impacted by the change.
```

Comment: Actually grouping table help us in improving SELECT performance and isolating the different client data, also using group we can move any group of stores/shops to a new database server for hardware scalling purpose, So it is helping us in that sense.

Comment: Now, data under a group of the table is increasing continuously, also few dead store data is there, we want to split that group into a more new group or move few stores data to already exist old group which has less load. Looking for solution to do this very efficiantly and fast.

Comment: @Irfan.gwb - The size and arrangement of the data in a table makes little or no difference to performance.  (OK, there are exceptions; please spell out a specific case.)

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use mySQL partition table to your propose, of course if I could understand what you are proposing. I having been using PARTITION tables to a lot of proposes where, and we have some tables with almost of 100 millions of reports.

Here some examples.

Creating a customers partitioned table by customer group name:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(30),
    customer_group CHAR(10),
    settings JSON, # very useful when you are working with no structured data
    created_at DATETIME
)
PARTITION BY LIST(store_id) (
    PARTITION g1 VALUES IN ('customer1'),
    PARTITION g2 VALUES IN ('customer2'),
    PARTITION g3 VALUES IN ('customer3')
);
```

Now you could insert some data:

```sql
INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES(1, 'Customer 1', 'customer1', '{}', NOW());
INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES(2, 'Customer 2', 'customer2', '{}', NOW());
INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES(3, 'Customer 3', 'customer3', '{}', NOW());
```

Of course that if you are not have a large table with lots of results, I think that these example may be not help you so much. But imagine that you want to add data from other customer and you don't want that these data create a mess with our other customers. So if you try to insert a "customer4" inside table `customers` you are been blocked by mySql, to do that you need to include another partition as follow:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `customers` ADD PARTITION (PARTITION `customer4` VALUES IN ('customer4'));
```

So, if you need now to delete some data from a large table and passing by parameter only the customer group, these will take some time but, as you are using partition tables, you could just do that.

If you want to delete all customer4 data:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `customers` TRUNCATE PARTITION `customer4`;
```

OR if you want to DROP some PARTITION like customer1 and 3, without affect the whole customers table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `customers` DROP PARTITION `customer1`,`customer3`;
```

If you want to make your system a quite more strict using the customer references into your queries, you could use PARTITION name inside you query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `customers` PARTITION(`customer2`);
```

The result of this query will be a simple line with customer2 data.

These are some simple examples that that you could do with PARTITIONS tables, I don't know with you had read about it, if don't I think that it could be an option to you, otherwise I think that I don't understand you problem very well and I'm sorry for that. Hope that helps!

[These more references](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it's not exactly about my question but you open one more door to handle this kind of situation. gone through the partitioning https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-partition.php seems interesting to me, I'll be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: I have one more question for you, I have 1 store_id field in all my 350 tables, now I want to create the partition based on store_id (all table data should be partitioned by store_id) and this partition should be dynamic means when new store_id came then there should be a new partition for it, which partition should go with?

Comment: Do partioning will help and parform well with this kind of JOIN queries: `SELECT c.*, cx.*
FROM `tbl_customers` AS `c`
LEFT JOIN `aio_customer_extra` AS `cx` ON `c`.`id` = `cx`.`customer_id`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_customers_address` AS `ca` ON `ca`.`id` = `cx`.`customer_default_address_id`
WHERE (c.store_id = '1234');`

Comment: Glad to hear that it help you, answerer your question you could create a partition by key and specifying just the size of the partition, so, if one new store_id came they will be inserted on table inside one of the partition defined by the size that you created. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-key.html)

Comment: What about the join query that I asked, I did little more research about partition got the mixed response with respect to performance, I am worried now it will not perform well with joins our most of the queries have joins.

Comment: I don't know about that, I have using partitions with some tables that have millions of records and a lot of joins, unions and subqueries and it continue to performing pretty well, if you want more performance try to create your queries specifying the partitions names.